Failed building wheel for tflite-support
Using pip install tflite-support, this is the full output and error message:
Collecting tflite-support
  Using cached tflite-support-0.1.0a1.tar.gz (390 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.4 in c:\users\luisd\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from tflite-support) (2.13.5)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\luisd\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from tflite-support) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\luisd\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from tflite-support) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: tflite-support
  Building wheel for tflite-support (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [95 lines of output]
      C:\Users\luisd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py:94: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support
      copying tflite_support\codegen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support
      copying tflite_support\metadata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support
      copying tflite_support\metadata_schema_py_generated.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support
      copying tflite_support\schema_py_generated.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support
      copying tflite_support\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support
      running egg_info
      writing tflite_support.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to tflite_support.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing entry points to tflite_support.egg-info\entry_points.txt
      writing requirements to tflite_support.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to tflite_support.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'tflite_support.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      writing manifest file 'tflite_support.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\Users\luisd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:218: _Warning: Package 'tflite_support.flatbuffers' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'tflite_support.flatbuffers' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'tflite_support.flatbuffers' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'tflite_support.flatbuffers' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'tflite_support.flatbuffers' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying tflite_support\metadata_schema.fbs -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\encode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\number_types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\packer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      running build_ext
      building '_pywrap_codegen' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\tensorflow
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\tensorflow\lite
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\tensorflow\lite\experimental
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\tensorflow\lite\experimental\support
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\tensorflow\lite\experimental\support\codegen
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\luisd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -IC:\Users\luisd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -Iinclude -Isrc -IC:\Users\luisd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\luisd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" /EHsc /Tpsrc\tensorflow\lite\experimental\support\codegen\android_java_generator.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\tensorflow\lite\experimental\support\codegen\android_java_generator.obj /EHsc /DVERSION_INFO=\\\"0.1.0a1\\\"
      android_java_generator.cc
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\yvals.h(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tflite-support
  Running setup.py clean for tflite-support
Failed to build tflite-support
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (tflite-support)

I tried pip install tflite-support --use-pep517, but it also doesn't work.
Can someone help me?

Try running vcvarsall.bat x64 (should be in some sub-folder of C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC) prior to running the pip install command. Also make sure that you have the Windows 10 SDK installed in the VS installer

Have you followed the full instructions for building from source https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows ? If not, or if you don't want to, consider finding a built binary (wheel) for Windows to install directly without building your own.

I ran into the same issue today; this should be due to the Python version (3.12).
After installing Python 3.11, pip install tflite-support worked for me.
If someone is having trouble installing Python 3.11 (like I did on Manjaro Linux), here is the solution I used:

Install pyenv (macOS, Linux) or pyenv-win (Windows), and then run:
pyenv install 3.11
pyenv global 3.11
python -V #output should be Python 3.11.10
pip install --upgrade pip #if needed
pip install tflite-support

Output of pip list should be:
absl-py 2.1.0, cffi 1.17.1, flatbuffers 24.3.25, numpy 2.1.3, pip 24.3.1, protobuf 3.20.3, pybind11 2.13.6, pycparser 2.22, setuptools 65.5.0, sounddevice 0.5.1, tflite-support 0.4.4
